# uploading files with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an upload form which allows the users to select files and upload it along with a title. The upload is done though ajax. The problem is only the value in the titles are being passed not the files.

The rows are added dynamically...

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <table width="100%" id="data">
</table>
<input name="submit" type="submit"  value="Submit"/>  
<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add new row" /> 
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rowitem = 1;
    $('#add').click(function() {
        rowitem++;
        $('#items').val(rowitem);
        var dynarow = '<tr><td>PDF</td><td>:</td><td><input id="uploadfile1" name="userfile[]" accept="application/pdf" class="btn btn-next upload" type="file" required></td><td>Title:</td><td width="17%"><input name="actual[]"  type="text" /></td><td width="7%"></td> <td width="3%">: </td></tr>';
        $('#data').append(dynarow);

    });


    $("#upload").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(form).serialize(),

                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {

                        alert("success");
                    } else {

                        alert("error");

                    }


                },
                error: function(data) {

                    alert("error");
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;


        }


    });


});
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this

```
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
```